# Can I use a 640x200 STN LCD controller to drive a 640x240 STN LCD display?

Tags: lcd, stn

I have an old LCD display controller that drives a 640x200 STN LCD display. The interface has a Frame Pulse/Frame Line Marker (FP/FLM), Line Pulse (LP), and LCD Clock control lines and D0..3 data lines.

Given the scarcity of 640x200 displays, I was wondering if it could use the controller with a 640x240 display panel. If after sending data for the first 200 rows the controller generates a FP/FLM, will a 640x240 panel simply display the first 200 rows correctly with no adverse side effects from not writing data to the remaining 40 rows? Or will those remaining rows suffer from bias or other issues?

This question would apply to any LCD controller using the standard control signals above being used to drive a display with more rows than the controller supports. Does the energising activity up to row 200 bleed over to rows 201 to 240 above over time, resulting in a DC bias effect? It’s something that isn’t covered in a data sheet, but through experience.

Comment: If this was the only difference it might work, though it's hard to know if there'd be garbage in the other area.  But first you'd have to be sure the interfaces were entirely compatible in all respects but row count.  It's really hard for this to be answerable based only on first principles and the limited information you've presented.  It feels like the sort of thing that might be worth trying if you had the parts on hand and a slow afternoon, but a questionable investment just to try.  Capturing the output to something else probably can work though.

Comment: For the purposes of anyone answering the question please assume that the interfaces are entirely compatible, except that the display has more rows than the controller is sending data for before asserting FLM and starting with the first row again. I’m hoping someone who has a lot of experience using LCDs can shed some light on what happens to the LCD - over time - when not every row is being driven.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I suspect it would work perfectly well the first time I tried it. Although perhaps not. However I’m asking about any cumulative issues over time. If for example row 201+ experienced a DC bias, despite not being driven directly, then the STN liquid crystal will degrade.

Comment: Are there any DC signals being applied elsewhere?  It seems like most of what you are driving is AC, so coupling probably would be, too.   But what's the goal here?  I wouldn't think you'd want to design a product this way.  For a one-off retrofit of valuable equipment replacing the display if it goes bad could be an option, or look for 640x200 1980's laptops in people's attics.

Comment: A controller will provide a stepped bias that should deliver no net DC for the row being driven. But I don’t know what happens to those rows that would never be driven, in terms of any long-term bleed effect from driven rows. This is for a retrofit, not a new design. However I don’t think I’ll find a laptop with this resolution, it’s CGA. A laptop from the 80s is more likely to provide a 640x480 display - to which my question also applies.

Comment: 640x480 came quite a bit later.  Your classic PC/XT equivalent laptops of the 1980's like the T1000 and its counterparts mostly were 200 rows high, as indeed they implemented CGA which wouldn't have had the issues on an LCD that it did on a CRT.